# Parsing remote JSON using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an application using WorldBank API, but WorldBank API does not support JSONP. So is there a way to parse remote JSON using Javascript. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot send direct AJAX calls to different domains. You may take a look at the [following guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) for different solutions. Since JSONP is out of the equation for you, an alternative would be to use a server side script that will act as a bridge between your domain and the distant domain.

Comment: Hello Thanks for responding, Will creating a proxy affect performance of the application??

Comment: @NeoStar, this will depend on how you implement it but in all cases there will be a performance penalty due to the additional requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can create kind of proxy. If using php, U can consume JSON in php script, and then serve it in your domain (where js works)

Cannot send direct AJAX to different domain because of Same Origin Policy.